# How can I run a new thread without slowing down the main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-input, python-multithreading

I have a script that processes some incoming data. While this script (lets call it "thread0") is processing the data (it does this in an infinite loop, since it is always waiting for new data to  arrive), I would like it to spawn a single new independent thread (thread1) that will prompt for user input without affecting the main thread. The idea is for thread1 to take the user input (an integer value), and execute a command whenever a user enters an integer value.

All my humble attempts so far (code included below) have been unsuccessful since I am not able to enter input into thread1. Any thoughts on how I could fix this?

My ultimate goal is to be able to run the main script, and then just enter a number (followed by pressing "enter") at any time so that the corresponding command is executed while not interrupting the main script. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

I would also be open to suggestions on other ways I could achieve this (I'm still learning Python)... Thanks everyone in advance!

```py
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

# setting some initial variables (needed?)
correction_in_counts = 0
correction_in_degrees = 0


# a custom function that will run commands for new thread ("thread1")
def task():
    while True:
        print "This is from the newly spawned thread.\n"
        correction_in_degrees = int(raw_input("Enter correction (degrees): "))
        correction_in_counts  = int(correction_in_degrees * 5.6)
        print "I received: ", correction_in_degrees
        print "I calculated: ", correction_in_counts


# create & run a new thread ("thread1")
thread = Thread(target=task)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()


while True:
    print "-------------------------------"
    print "HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0)."

    # during this time, I'd like for "thread1" to be running so that I
    # can enter interger values at any time


    print "DEGREES received from TASK FUNCTION: ", correction_in_degrees
    print "COUNTS received from TASK FUNCTION: ", correction_in_counts
```

Comment: It seems from your code you are using Python 2 - -

That really is a  "NO, that is old, unsuported and unmaintained". What version of Python 3 can you get there?

Comment: The code *does* work, but the task only runs once and the `print` output is mixed with the main thread.  You probably want a `while True:` in `task`.  Add a `sleep(1)` in the main thread to slow it down and see the output from `task`.